# Displaying function progress in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-ui

```
 $("#processorTeam").click(function(e) {
    $("#processingDialog").dialog().html('Processing Started')
    var funcCall = processImages(e);
})
```

This code initiates a jQueryUI dialog box, populates the text with 'Processing Started', and then runs the processImages function.

In Firefox and Chrome, the dialog box displays before the processImages function runs, and then displays status messages during the running of the processImages function.

In IE, the dialog box doesn't display until the processImages function is completed.  At that time it also shows all the status messages that were sent during the running of the processImages function.

Is there a way to do this work in IE7  & IE8 like it does in Firefox?

Comment: progress images is a rather involved function with calls to ColdFusion CFC's but because it is so involved is why I want to populate the dialog box with what procedures have been run and if there was an error. I have been populating a div with the messages but have had the same problem in IE.  I wish they would not insist on using IE for the process.

Comment: Yes, but are the calls to the CFCs asynchronous or not?

Comment: They are being done through cfajaxproxy so I don't think there was an option to not have it asynch AND it works okay in Firefox/Chrome.    I am using Railo which I am not as familiar with so I will have to look at the documentation to see if there is an option to force the asynch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmz... a quick fix to this would be a small timeout

```
 $("#processorTeam").click(function(e) {
    $("#processingDialog").dialog().html('Processing Started')
    setTimeout(function(){var funcCall = processImages(e);}, 100);
})
```

Could work :-? lemme know what changes, if anything...

Comment: That did work to show the dialog box before the function started but then IE threw up an error and stopped processing the page:Message: Member not found.
Line: 67
Char: 177
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:8888/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js

The code still worked as desired in Firefox.

Comment: hmz, I suspect it has smth to do with var funcCall... try putting the declaration outside the setTimeout and using it as intended meaning =>var funcCall;setTimeout(function(){funcCall = processImages(e);}, 100);
P.S. I also have a missing ";" before setTimeout in my initial example, IE has been known to dislike random things... Keep me posted, it has to be an easy fix.

Comment: When I took the processImages function out of the set timeout, I didn't get any errors and the function ran, BUT the dialog box did not open or populate until the function was done processing.